# How to make a class decorator friendly for pylance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylance

I'm using **pylance** and enabled the **strict mode**, and hoping for better developing experience.

It works well until I define some **class decorator**

```
def struct(cls : Type[Any]) -> Type[Any]:
    # ... do some magic here ...
    return dataclass(frozen=True)(cls)

@struct
class Vec:
    x: int
    y: int

print(Vec(1, "abc")) # no error msg here, no hints about constructor arguments also.
```

Here, when I'm typing `Vec(`, there is no hints about types of constructor arguments, and when I'm typing `Vec(1, "abc")`, there is no type error occurs.

And I find that defining `@struct` as generic function (instead of use Any) makes things even worse:

```
A = TypeVar("A")

def struct(cls : Type[A]) -> Type[A]:
    # ... do some magic here ...
    return dataclass(frozen=True)(cls)

@struct
class Vec:
    x: int
    y: int

print(Vec(1, 2)) # type error here: Expected no arguments to Vec
```

In this case, when I'm typing `Vec(1, 2)`, a type error occurs, and it says "Expected no arguments to Vec", which is not expected.

I hope that there is some way I can **tell pylance** (or other static linter) about the **meta information of the returned class** (maybe generated from the original class via `typing.get_type_hints`, but there is a promise from me that the metadata of the returned class is not dynamically modified after that).

I noticed that pylance can deal with `@dataclass` very well, so I think there might be **some mechanism** to achieve that.

Is there any way to do that? or `@dataclass` is just special processed by pylance?

Comment: Interesting: `struct = dataclass` works but `struct = dataclass(frozen=True)` fails.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but: It is impossible to tell the signature of your class before hand. Obviously undecorated class written like that has a generic object signature. Thus, until you actually create your class at runtime it is impossible to tell what it is supposed to accept. Which means *static* type checking has no way of predicting that.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, [PEP 681 (Data Class Transforms)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/) may be able to help you -- provided that you would be able to use Python 3.11 (at the time of writing, only pre-release versions of Python 3.11 are available)

Data class transforms were added to allow library authors to annotate functions or classes which provide behaviour similar to `dataclasses.dataclass`. The intended use case seems to be exactly what you are describing: allow static type checkers to infer when code is generated dynamically in a "dataclass-like" way. The PEP introduces a single decorator, `typing.dataclass_transform`. This decorator can be used to mark functions or classes that dynamically generate "dataclass-like" classes. If necessary, the decorator also allows you to specify some details about the generated classes (e.g. whether `__eq__` is implemented by default). For all details, you can checkout [PEP 681](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/) or [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.dataclass_transform).

The most basic case would be changing your code to

```
@dataclass_transform()  # <-- from typing import dataclass_transform
def struct(cls : Type[Any]) -> Type[Any]:
    # ... do some magic here ...
    return dataclass(frozen=True)(cls)
```

If you now write

```
print(Vec(1, "abc"))
```

You will get an error from PyLance:

```
Argument of type "Literal['2']" cannot be assigned to parameter "y" of type "int" in function "__init__"
"Literal['2']" is incompatible with "int"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

If I understand correctly, `dataclass_transform` should also fix your second case.

---

*Edit after a request for a more general mechanism*

Using inheritance and metaclasses, you can push the boundaries of `dataclass_transform` a bit further. The special thing about `dataclass_transform` is that is allows you to annotate something which you normally cannot annotate: it allows static type checkers to infer that methods are generated dynamically, with a (`@dataclass` compatible) signature.

If you want all classes to have some common functionality, you can use inheritance in stead of a class decorator, like in the example below:

```
@typing.dataclass_transform()
class BaseClass:

    def shared_method(self):
        print('This method is shared by all subclasses!')


class Vec(BaseClass):
    x: int 
    y: int
```

However, this is of course fairly limited. You probably want to add dynamically generated methods to your class. Luckily, we can do this too. However, we will need metaclass for this.

Consider the following example:

```
@typing.dataclass_transform()
class Metaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls,
                name: str, 
                bases: tuple[type],
                class_dict: dict[str, typing.Any],
                **kwargs: typing.Any):
        self = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, class_dict, **kwargs)
        annotations: dict[str, type] = getattr(self, '__annotations__', {})
        if annotations:
            squares = '+'.join(
                f'self.{name}**2' 
                for name, data_type in annotations.items() 
                if issubclass(data_type, numbers.Number)
            )
            source = f'def length(self): return math.sqrt({squares})'
            namespace = {}
            exec(source, globals(), namespace)
            setattr(self, 'length', namespace['length'])
        # You can also generate your own __init__ method here.
        # Sadly, PyLance does not agree with this line.
        # I do not know how to fix this.
        return dataclass(frozen=True)(self) 
    
class BaseClass(metaclass=Metaclass):

    def length(self) -> float:
        return 0.0


class Vec(BaseClass):
    x: int 
    y: int 


print(Vec(1, 2).length())
```

The metaclass scans all annotations, and generates a method `length`. It assumes that all its child classes are vectors, where all fields annotated with a numerical type are entries of the vector. The generated `length` method then uses these entries to compute the length of the vector.

The trouble we now face is how to make sure the PyLance knows that classes using this metaclass have a `length` method which returns a float. To achieve this, we first define a base class using this metaclass, which has a correctly annotated `length` method. All your vector classes can now inherit from this baseclass. They will have their `length` method generated automatically, and PyLance is happy too.

There are still limitations to this. You cannot generate methods with a dynamic signature. (e.g. you cannot generate a method `def change_values(self, x: int, y: int)`). This is because there is simply no way to annotate that in the child class. That is part of the magic of `dataclass_transform`: the ability to annotate a dynamic signature for the `__init__` method.

Comment: Thanks, this is a limited solution,  it works only when the behavior of my class decorator is similar to @dataclass,  but what if not ?  Is there any mechanism which is more general ?

Comment: @luochen1990 I expanded my answer a bit with some ideas one could use to go beyond `dataclass_transform` -- although you would probably still need it. Do you have any examples in mind where you want to do something with dynamic class creation which is not similar to @dataclass?

Comment: I want to add some method to cls   at  `... do some magic here ...`, and hopes pylance can be notified that there is extra methods in the instance of this class.